# Somar Registros Com Dados Específicos

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, pascal, object-pascal

Bom, atualmente estou trabalhando num projeto no qual usamos ClientDataSet's para comunicar com o banco de dados.
Meu problema é o Seguinte, Tenho um relatório de Recebimento no Setor de Exportação, em que tem vários registros em Várias Moedas diferentes.Eu preciso Somar o Valor das Parcelas do Recebimento, com Base na Sua Moeda, pesquisei alguns métodos de fazê-lo com uma repetição que passava um parâmetro e somava o **valor_a_receber** com base em uma moeda específica, mas neste caso eu precisaria especificar cada uma das moedas, são mais de 150.

```
    while not CDSGrid.Eof do
  begin
  if cdsgrid.fielbyname('ID_MOEDA').AsInteger = 155 Then
  begin  
   ValorReceber := cdsgrid.fielbyname('valor_a_receber').AsExtended + 
 ValorReceber
    CDSGrid.Next;
  end;
```

Estou Usando O Servidor MySQL 8.0, consigo distinguir as moedas por um campo chamado **ID_MOEDA** que contém somente 1 id específico para cada moeda (Ex.: ID_MOEDA Do Euro = 155);

[image: Exemplo de Como São Exibidos os Dados]

Olhando um pouco no framework, consegui identificar o que é feito para trazer os dados da tabela do relatório (mostrarei aqui abreviada, pois algumas informações não são relevantes para a questão)

```
 SELECT
      CAST(CONCAT(`lr`.`ID`,`pr`.`ID`) AS UNSIGNED) AS `ID`,
      CONCAT(`lr`.`NUMERO_DOCUMENTO`,'-',`pr`.`NUMERO_PARCELA`,'/',`lr`.`QUANTIDADE_PARCELA`) AS `DOCUMENTO`,
      `lr`.`ID`                        AS `ID_LANCAMENTO_RECEBER`,
      `lr`.`QUANTIDADE_PARCELA`        AS `QUANTIDADE_PARCELA`,
      `lr`.`VALOR_A_RECEBER`           AS `VALOR_LANCAMENTO`,
      `lr`.`NUMERO_DOCUMENTO`          AS `NUMERO_DOCUMENTO`,
      `lr`.`ID_PROCESSO_EXPORTACAO`    AS `ID_PROCESSO_EXPORTACAO`,
      `exportacao_processo`.`SITUACAO` AS `SITUACAO`,
      `pr`.`VALOR_RECEBIDO`            AS `VALOR_RECEBIDO`,
      `pr`.`VALOR_RECEBER`             AS `VALOR_RECEBER`,
      `lr`.`ID_MOEDA`                  AS `ID_MOEDA`,
      `moeda`.`NOME`                   AS `NOME_MOEDA`

    FROM (((((((`fin_lancamento_receber` `lr`
             JOIN `fin_parcela_receber` `pr`)
            JOIN `pessoa` `p`)
           JOIN `cliente` `c`)
          JOIN `fin_status_parcela` `s`)
         JOIN `conta_caixa` `cc`)
        JOIN `moeda`
          ON ((`lr`.`ID_MOEDA` = `moeda`.`ID`)))
       LEFT JOIN `exportacao_processo`
         ON ((`exportacao_processo`.`ID` = `lr`.`ID_PROCESSO_EXPORTACAO`)))
    WHERE ((`pr`.`ID_FIN_LANCAMENTO_RECEBER` = `lr`.`ID`)
           AND (`pr`.`ID_FIN_STATUS_PARCELA` = `s`.`ID`)
           AND (`lr`.`ID_CLIENTE` = `c`.`ID`)
           AND (`c`.`ID_PESSOA` = `p`.`ID`)
           AND (`pr`.`ID_CONTA_CAIXA` = `cc`.`ID`))
```

A Minha ideia é  **Calcular o Total de "Valor Recebido" em Dolar, Euro, Libra, etc.. de Um Jeito Dinâmico que varra todos os registros, identifique as Moedas, e faça um totalizador para cada Moeda.**

Tipo :

```
|===========================================|
|id_moeda |nome_moeda|valor_total_a_receber |
|===========================================|
|155      | EURO     |155.251,65            | 
|84       |LIBRA     |25.486,98             |
|===========================================|
```

Comment: Você precisa fazer isso diretamente no CDS? Pois podia fazer pelo SQL esse tratamento...

Comment: Não Preciso Necessariamente fazer pelo CDS, inclusive ja tentei, mas não consigo pensar em outros modos para fazê-lo mesmo cogitando o SQL, não faço a mínima ideia de por onde começar o código.

Comment: Nos mostre o seu SQL, edite sua pergunta e informe o SQL que está utilizando para trazer os dados! E diga também como você faz para distinguir entre os tipos de moedas.

Comment: Pronto, coloquei os detalhes requeridos

Comment: Desculpa, me expressei mal, as informações que colocou são úteis também, mas digo para nos mostrar a sua Query (O SELECT que você faz para trazer os dados do banco) que você tentou até agora. Dessa forma, também ajudará para que sua pergunta seja liberada novamente.

Comment: Não usei um select, pois por trás do sistema tem toda uma framework que ja faz isso, apresentei o código que usei para somar o valor de uma moeda específica, mas que no caso nao daria certo para o que eu estava precisando, pois preciso de algo dinâmico que não precise ser informado a moeda, e sim identificar quais moedas existem na tabela e fazer um totalizador do valor (**valor_a_receber**) referente a moeda

Comment: SELECT ID_MOEDA, SUM( VALOR_A_RECEBE), SUM( VALOR_TOTAL ) FROM TABELA GROUP BY  ID_MOEDA

Comment: Cara é exatamente isso, consegui trazer os registros somados corretamente, agora a parte de integrar isso no sistema é comigo! Tem alguma Maneira de você postar como resposta? ou so quando o post for liberado?